# How are handlers set for Plugin.MauiMTAdmob?

Tags: c#, android, ads, maui

I am trying to add **ads** to my App but I am having some exceptions.
When I installed the
Plugin.MauiMTAdmob and ran the the app, I had the error **ump**( *user massaging platform*) then I tried to solved the error by adding the plug-in **xamarin.google.UsermassagingPlatform**.
Now when I run the app it shows the error (**Microsoft.Maui.Platform.HandlerNotFoundException:** 'Handler not found for view Plugin.MauiMTAdmob.Controls.MTAdView.)

Answer (score 3):

As shown in the repo example [here][1] in`MauiProgram.cs` make sure that the >>> highlighted <<< line is included:

```
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
            >>> .UseMauiMTAdmob() <<<
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                });

            return builder.Build();
        }


  [1]: https://github.com/marcojak/MauiMTAdmob/blob/master/SampleMMTAdmob/MauiProgram.cs
```